# Version filed in many-to-one relation causes object references an unsaved transient instance

Tags: java, hibernate, concurrency, orm, version

i have a class like this :

```
public class User(){
        private String name;
        private Integer version ; 

        //getter & setter 
}
```

and the hibernate mapping file is :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="org.model.User" table="User">
        <id name="id" column="Id" type="java.lang.Integer">
            <generator class="sequence" >
                <param name="sequence">SEQ_User</param>   
            </generator>
        </id>
        <version name="version" column="version" type="Integer" />
        <property name="name"    column="Name"   type="string" not-null="true"  />
 </class>

</hibernate-mapping>
```

when i use as a many-to-one relation like this :

```
public class UserDetail(){
        private String tel;
        private User    user;
   // getter & setter 
    }
```

and this is UserDetail.hbm.xml file :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="org.model.UserDetail" table="User_Detail">
        <id name="id" column="Id" type="java.lang.Integer">
            <generator class="sequence" >
                <param name="sequence">SEQ_User_Detail</param>   
            </generator>
        </id>

        <property name="tel"    column="tel"   type="string" not-null="true"  />
        <many-to-one name="user"            column="user_Id"        entity-name="org.model.User" />

 </class>

</hibernate-mapping>
```

when i want to save the UserDetail take this exception :

> object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient
>   instance before flushing

i save the UserDetail object in the way below :

```
@Override
    public void add(UserDetail entity) {
        Session session = getSession();
        session.save(entity);
    }
```

and i set User in the UserDetail like this :

```
entity.setUser(new User(1));
```

i just know the UserId and never load the user object.

Comment: That's because you lack a cascade or you are linking a transient entity to an entity that you want to persist.Try adding the code for `UserDetails` and the data access layer code that performs the save.

Comment: i don't have any problem when i remove version field

Answer (score 0):

Although you haven't added the code for `UserDetails` and the persistence logic, I suppose you have a `@ManyToOne` association to a `User` in `UserDetails`.

If you have a `User` and a `UserDetails` that you want to persist, you have to call persist() on both entities. Unless you have a parent-side association in `User`, you cannot use cascading since [cascade makes sense only from parent to children but not vice versa](https://vladmihalcea.com/a-beginners-guide-to-jpa-and-hibernate-cascade-types/).

This has nothing to do with concurrency or versioning as you initially suspected.

You said that:

> I don't have any problem when i remove version field

That could be explained if you set an id to a transient `User` instance and you try to call `persist()`:

```
User user = new User();
user.setId(1L);
user.setVersion(0);
session.persist(user);
```

Because you have a sequence identifier generator, it is Hibernate that should assign identifiers. Also, the version property should never be assigned manually. If you have a detached entity, [you need to call merge instead of persist](https://vladmihalcea.com/jpa-persist-and-merge/).

### Update

According to your update and the new source code, I can't find any particular issue. However, you should know that the `Session` might have been opened before and maybe there are other entities that you added previously to creating the `User` entity. It's only [during the flush](https://vladmihalcea.com/a-beginners-guide-to-jpahibernate-flush-strategies/) that [entity state transitions](https://vladmihalcea.com/a-beginners-guide-to-jpa-hibernate-entity-state-transitions/) are propagated to the DB.

Comment: Problems on saving userDetail not user , but just user have version feild

Comment: You really need to learn how to ask a question. Try putting yourself in someone else's shoes and try to figure out if you can understand the problem without seeing all the code.

Comment: i check all of the things but my problem does not solve

Comment: I have no idea what else could cause your problem. You need to debug it to find out what's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

after i debug if we put the version field Null in User i get the exception but when i set it with zero the problem is solved